# Wrong UninitializedPropertyAccessException in Kotlin after property initialization

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have Dagger2 injected property in my presenter.

```
@Inject lateinit var dataInteractor: DataInteractor
```

It is accessed in couple of methods. In one of them `loadAppointments()` everything works fine but in another `refund()` `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` is thrown. The code has been working well for a while and this issue has raised the only couple of days ago.
No Kotlin updates were installed before.

```
import android.util.Log
import co.example.Application
import co.example.domain.model.entity.AppointmentsEntity
import co.example.domain.model.entity.ProvidersEntity
import co.example.interactor.data.DataInteractor
import co.example.domain.di.base.RxDisposablePresenter
import co.example.view.operation.OperationView
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import java.util.*
import javax.inject.Inject

class AppointmentsPresenter : RxDisposablePresenter<AppointmentsPresenter.View>() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dataInteractor: DataInteractor

    private lateinit var operationView: OperationView<*>

    private val results: ArrayList<AppointmentsEntity.AppointmentEntity> = ArrayList()
    private val resultsHistory: ArrayList<AppointmentsEntity.AppointmentEntity> = ArrayList()

    override fun onTakeView(view: View?) {
        super.onTakeView(view)
        operationView = view?.operationView()!!
    }

    fun loadAppointments() {
        val userID = Application.appComponent.userInternalStorage().userID()
        if (userID != null) {
            add(dataInteractor
                    .getAppointments(userID, LIMIT, OFFSET)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnSubscribe { operationView.showProgress() }
                    .doFinally {
                        operationView.hideProgress()
                        view?.onAppointmentsDataFilled(results, resultsHistory)
                    }
                    .subscribe(
                            {
                                divideUpcomingAndCompleteAppointments(it)
                                view?.unblockAppointments()
                            },
                            {
                                val message = it.message
                                if (message!!.contains("blocked")) {
                                    view?.blockAppointments()
                                    operationView.showError("Error")
                                    return@subscribe
                                }
                                operationView.showError(message)

                            }
                    ))
        }
    }

    fun refund(position: Int?) {
        add(dataInteractor
                .refund(results[position!!].id!!)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe { operationView.showProgress() }
                .doFinally {
                    operationView.hideProgress()
                }
                .subscribe(
                        {
                            view?.onRefundCompleted()
                        },
                        {
                            val message = it.message
                            operationView.showError(message!!)
                        }
                ))
    }

    private fun divideUpcomingAndCompleteAppointments(appointmentsEntity: AppointmentsEntity) {
        results.clear()
        resultsHistory.clear()
        for (appointment in appointmentsEntity.results!!) {
            if (appointment.status.equals(STATUS_COMPLETE, true)) {
                resultsHistory.add(appointment)
            } else {
                results.add(appointment)
            }
        }
    }

    fun loadProviderById(doctorId: Long?, onDoctorRetrivedListener: (ProvidersEntity.ProviderEntity) -> Unit) {
        add(
                dataInteractor
                        .getProviders(0, 100, 0, 0)
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(
                                { providersEntity ->
                                    val doctor = providersEntity
                                            .results
                                            ?.filter {
                                                Log.d("ATAT", "loadProviderById: ${it.user_id}")
                                                it.user_id == doctorId
                                            }
                                    doctor?.let {
                                        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                                            onDoctorRetrivedListener.invoke(doctor[0])
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    val message = it.message
                                    operationView.showError(message!!)
                                }))
    }

    interface View {
        fun operationView(): OperationView<*>
        fun onAppointmentsDataFilled(appointments: ArrayList<AppointmentsEntity.AppointmentEntity>?,
                                     appointmentsHistory: ArrayList<AppointmentsEntity.AppointmentEntity>?)

        fun onRefundCompleted()
        fun blockAppointments()
        fun unblockAppointments()
    }

    companion object {
        const val STATUS_COMPLETE = "Complete"
        const val LIMIT: Long = 1000
        const val OFFSET: Long = 0
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
2018-12-13 11:59:29.359 4808-4808/co.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: co.example, PID: 4808
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dataInteractor has not been initialized
        at co.example.presenter.appointements.AppointmentsPresenter.refund(AppointmentsPresenter.kt:59)
        at co.example.view.appointements.AppointmentsFragment.refundRequest(AppointmentsFragment.kt:123)
        at co.example.activity.MainActivity.onRefundRequested(MainActivity.kt:295)
        at co.example.view.dialog.RefundDialogFragment$onCreateDialog$1.onClick(RefundDialogFragment.kt:16)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:172)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

UPD:
Doesn't reproduce if fragment that calls these methods is created as singleton.